# SSRS Unauthorized 401 with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, ssl, reporting-services, bids

I have configured SSRS and the SharePoint integration and everything works fine without SSL turned on.

I can create reports in SSRS (BIDS) and connect to SharePoint lists and they run. I can create reports through SharePoint document libraries and they run perfectly fine.

As soon as I turn on "require SSL" in IIS for my SharePoint site I start running into problems. Suddenly I can no longer use localhost in my datasource connections in BIDS of course so that causes problems. As soon as I switch it to my public https:// URL I can no longer get it to work. I receive a 401 unauthorized error.

I have tried adding an "execution account" to SSRS which didnt appear to help. I tried specifying credentials other than just Windows Authentication through the SSRS data source and that gives me another error saying that the addon doesnt support anything other than Windows Authentication. I tried connecting through Report Builder 3.0 through the web from a remote box and I get the same errors.

using SharePoint 2010 Foundation and SQL Server 2008 r2 on Windows Server 2008 r2.

Comment: Is it an issue with the certificate. I am sure SSRS will not handle certificate errors gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one thing i did not try when I failed to figure out how to do what you are doing.

> When configuring report server integration in Central Administration,
>   specify the report server URL in this format:
>   `https://<SSLCertifcateName>:<SSLport>/reportserver.`
>
> For more information, see How to: Configure the Report Server Integration
>   Feature in SharePoint Central Administration

.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223%28v=sql.90%29.aspx